# Magento 2 new theme from scratch how to delete content below footer

Tags: magento2, theme, remove-block

I have created a new theme from scratch (so it doesn't inherit any themes). 
I have added my custom css, moved some blocks, removed some blocks without any difficulties.

But I have one problem, there is content below my footer which I was not able to remove, I couldn't find which block was causing this problem. It shows in every single page, I found that if I remove the block "content" then it's removed but the content above the footer is obviously deleted too.

Here is an image showing the content I'm trying to remove
[image: content below footer]

I'm not totally sure if I should remove it or hide it with some javascript and make it shows at a particular moment.

I activated the template hints and it didn't help at all, it doesn't display any templates on the part I want to remove.

**EDIT**
The only third party module I have installed is Mollie for payment.

Here is my Theme_dir/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="header.container" destination="header.panel.navbar"/>
        <move element="page.top" destination="header.panel.menu.navbar"/>
        <move element="logo" destination="header.panel.navbar" before="header.panel"/>
        <move element="top.search" destination="header.panel.navbar" before="header.panel"/>
        <move element="authorization-link" destination="header.panel.justify" before="store_language"/>
        <move element="minicart" destination="header.panel.justify" after="store_language"/>
        <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header.panel.menu.navbar" after="-"/>
        <move element="footer-container" destination="main.content" after="content"/>
        <referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="absolute_footer" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="frontend-storage-manager" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="store.menu" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="store.links" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="store.settings" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root" remove="true"/>
        <container name="header.container.panel.nav" htmlTag="header" before="main.content">
            <container name="header.panel.nav" htmlClass="bg-white fixed-top" htmlTag="nav" before="-">
                <container name="header.panel.navbar" htmlClass="navbar navbar-expand-md" htmlTag="div" before="-">
                    <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-3 col-7" after="top.search">
                        <container name="header.panel.justify" label="Page Header Panel Justify" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="d-flex justify-content-end left-nav-mobile">
                            <referenceBlock name="skip_to_content" remove="true"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="Magento_Store::switch/languages.phtml">
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\ViewModel\SwitcherUrlProvider</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </block>
                            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation" name="top.links">
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </block>
                        </container>
                    </container>
                </container>
                <container name="header.panel.menu.navbar" htmlClass="navbar menu navbar-expand-md" htmlTag="div" after="-">

                </container>
            </container>
        </container>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo-header.png</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" after="header.container.panel.nav">
            <referenceBlock name="content"/>
            <referenceBlock name="footer-container"/>
        </container>
    </body>
</page>
```

So if I add

```
<referenceBlock name="content" remove="true"/>
```

The block below my footer I want to delete is removed but the content above the footer is removed too.

Comment: This is apparently a form used to log in during checkout. Have you installed any third-party Checkout module? Can you show us how is your .xml file that you used to add / remove the blocks you mentioned?

Comment: @RoneClayBrasil thank you for your answer, I just edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I thought this was not a template since with template_hints enabled no path were displayed in the block I wanted to remove, I made a search in all the modules to find where it could come from, I searched for each div class I found.

I found that the template "authentication-popup.phtml" had the classes I was looking for so I searched which block added the template to the content.

I found

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup" name="authentication-popup" as="authentication-popup" template="Magento_Customer::account/authentication-popup.phtml">
            //Some arguments here
            </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

So I simply added

```
<referenceBlock name="authentication-popup" remove="true"/>
```

in **Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**